# Python ignore regex

Tags: python, regex

I am actually working on Python regex that excludes certain file path. I am creating this regex in a property file , and then passing to my python code

```
import re
regex = ".*-old-.*"
sequence = "/tmp/file-old-1"

print re.match(regex, sequence)
```

Now , I want to build a regex that do not match for anything. Is it possible to have so. Any help will be helpful !

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean? typically `regex` is used to match strings containing a pattern you define. When you say do not match anything, do you mean perform an action if your current regex has no match? Whats your input and expected output?

Comment: You tagged this for `python-3.x`, and it has a syntax error for Python 3, and guaranteed broken code in any version of Python (`//` is not a comment character in Python, so you're trying to divide the result of `re.match` by `True`). If you're going to provide code samples, at least make them legal code.

Answer (score 1):

There are the special characters `^` and `$` to denote the beggining and ending of the text being matched. Any pattern that have text *before* the beggining or *after* the end will have no match:

```
In [113]: re.findall(r".^", "any text")
Out[113]: []
```